# Javascript: how to load dropdown options based on radio selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a simple form that allows users to enter a frequency of a certain report. They would previously allow users to enter days of the week. As the demand for some reports shifted, they added workday and day of the month as an option. Now I'll be creating an interface to such where they would want users select either 'Days of the Week', 'Days of the Month' or 'Workday' thru a radio button, and having different dropdown options based on their selection.

```
<td>Day:</td> <td> <div class="controls">
                                <fieldset id="Group1" name="Group1">
                                    <label><input id="Radio1" name="Radio1" type="radio" value="day" />Days of Week<br /></label>
                                    <label><input id="Radio1" name="Radio1" type="radio" value="month_day" />Days of Month<br /></label>
                                    <label><input id="Radio1" name="Radio1" type="radio" value="work_day" />Workday<br /></label>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                                <fieldset id="Group2" name="Group2">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="days"  name="newday[]" multiple>
                                        <option value="monday">Monday</option>
                                        <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
                                        <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
                                        <option value="thursday">Thursday</option>
                                        <option value="friday">Friday</option>
                                        <option value="saturday">Saturday</option>
                                        <option value="sunday">Sunday</option>
                                        <option value="01">01</option>
                                        <option value="02">02</option>
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .
                                        <option value="31">31</option>
                                        <option value="wd 1">WD 1</option>
                                        <option value="wd 2">WD 2</option>
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .
                                        <option value="wd 25">WD 25</option>
                                    </select>
                                </fieldset>

                        </td>
```

[image: Snap]

I'm wondering what method is suitable for such as I'm new to either Ajax or jquery. Monday - Friday are the options shown if they selected 'Days of Week', 0 - 31 if 'Days of Month', wd 1 - wd 25 if 'Workday'. Thanks for any help in Advance. :)

Comment: for changing the values from the select depending on another option, yes, you will need of ajax. you will have to make a function that detects when you click/onchange of the radio button and the call the ajax to load into the day selector the values you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    // Group the select's options by the radio they correspond to
    var options = {},
        radios = $("#Group1 :radio");
    options[radios.eq(0).val()] = [];
    options[radios.eq(1).val()] = [];
    options[radios.eq(2).val()] = [];
    $("#Group2 select option").each(function(i, el) {
        var e = $(el);
        if (i < 7)
            options[radios.eq(0).val()].push(e);
        else if (i < 10) //38
            options[radios.eq(1).val()].push(e);
        else
            options[radios.eq(2).val()].push(e);
        e.remove();
    });

    // On radio's change, empty the select and append the options that correspond to the selected radio
    $("#Group1 :radio").on("change", function() {
        $("#Group2 select").empty();
        var arr = options[$(this).val()];
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            $("#Group2 select").append(arr[i]);
    }).filter(":selected").trigger("change");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/paska/85w47nbj/1/

Also note that you shouldn't have more than one element with the same id.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you're using jQuery pretty much easy. Take a look at the following running code here. Only you need to remove the identical id's for all the radio buttons otherwise that'd it harder to select that DOM because **ID's are unique**, else is fine.

```js
function showSameGroup(target1, target2, el){
    if(target1 == el){
        $(target2).find("option").show().not("."+el).hide();
    }
};
$("#Group1 input[type='radio']").click(function(){
var s1 = $(this).val(), s2 = $("#days");
    
    if(s1 == "day"){
        showSameGroup(s1, s2, "day");
    }
    else if(s1 == "mday"){
        showSameGroup(s1, s2, "mday");
    }
    else{
        showSameGroup(s1, s2, "wday");
    }
});
```

```html
<td>Day:</td> <td> <div class="controls">
        <fieldset id="Group1" name="Group1">
            <label><input  name="Radio1" type="radio" value="day" />Days of Week<br /></label>
            <label><input  name="Radio1" type="radio" value="mday" />Days of Month<br /></label>
            <label><input  name="Radio1" type="radio" value="wday" />Workday<br /></label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
        <fieldset id="Group2" name="Group2">
            <select class="form-control" id="days"  name="newday[]" multiple>
                <option class="day" value="monday">Monday</option>
                <option class="day" value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
                <option class="day" value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
                <option class="day" value="thursday">Thursday</option>
                <option class="day" value="friday">Friday</option>
                <option class="day" value="saturday">Saturday</option>
                <option class="day" value="sunday">Sunday</option>
                <option class="mday" value="01">01</option>
                <option class="mday" value="02">02</option>
               
                <option class="mday" value="31">31</option>
                <option class="wday" value="wd 1">WD 1</option>
                <option class="wday" value="wd 2">WD 2</option>
            
                <option class="wday" value="wd 25">WD 25</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>

</td>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I hope it works.

Comment: sorry real noob. Do I onload this function in body tag?

Comment: Yeah, You can or simply Put it anywhere inside the jQuery Ready function.

Comment: Nice :) ..Thanks for this too!